# jQuery .on click is not working inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

`$(document).on("click",...` is not working inside the `jQuery` plugin.

I have an `ul.box` element and I am adding some

```
<li> "data" <span class="close">  </span></li>
```

this `li` is dynamically adding and whenever I click on the

click event is not working .

### plugin

```
(function($) {
'use strict';
    $.fn.Multiauto = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({
            data_object : null,
            input_name : null,
            data_url : null,
        }, options);
        function  remove_tag(this_el){
            this_el.parent("li").remove();
        };
        $(document).on("click", "ul.box li span.close", function(){
            remove_tag($(this)) 
        });
        return this;    
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: is this element inside this_el? if yes you should try with $(this_el).on('click', li span.close,function(){})

Comment: extremly sorry..thanks for your answer. this is my mistake. i Forgot to add the class ".close"

to the span

Answer (score 0):

Your selector used in the jQuery on click

```
"ul.box li span.close"
```

should just be:

```
"ul li .close"
```

or, if it does not have any same class, only:

```
".close"
```

Comment: extremly sory..thanks for your answer. this is my mistake. i Forgot to add the class ".close"

to the span

Comment: Correct answers should be marked as accepted, though we know you forgot to add class .close

Answer (score 0):

If li is dynamically adding then you have to use on click event with delegate seee below:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Example code:

```
$("li").delegate("p", "click", function(){
    alert('its working');
});
```